# cannot convert from 'unsigned short [9]' to 'char []'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-strings, tchar, visual-studio-6

I am working on very old C++ project. When building my C++ code in Visual Studio 6 I am getting error *"cannot convert from 'unsigned short [9]' to 'char []'"*.

for code below:

```
char    variable[] = _T("something");
```

I googled and tried to understand the issue. It could be the way I am building it.

I've already tried the step written in https://mihai-nita.net/2006/07/23/visual-studio-unicode-projects/ (adding `UNICODE` & `_UNICODE` in preprocessor). It would be very helpful if someone can suggest a solution to correct this error.

Comment: Looks like `_T` is feeding you a wider-than `char` character. Either go all Unicode or don't use any Unicode. That said, it's 2018. Use the Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

The `_T` macro expands to either a narrow or wide string literal depending on the state of the `UNICODE` macro.  If `UNICODE` isn't defined `_T` will expand to a `char` string, and if `UNICODE` is defined `_T` will expand to a wide char string.

If you're using `_T`, you should use the type `TCHAR`, which will similarly expand to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on the state of the `UNICODE` macros:

```
TCHAR variable[] = _T("something");
```

This will expand to

```
char variable[] = "something";
```

if `UNICODE` is not defined, and will expand to something like

```
wchar_t variable[] = L"something";
```

if `UNICODE` is defined.

It's worth noting that `wchar_t` wasn't a real type in early versions of Visual C++, but rather just a `typedef` for (or macro expanding to) `unsigned short`, which is why the error message you're seeing references that instead of `wchar_t`.